# While trying to jump to specific time in video player the video pause for a split second before continuing normally on new time

Tags: android, flutter, dart, exoplayer

I am using VideoPlayerController seekTo method to move forward or backward the video by 10 sec but the video pauses for a while before continuing on the new time

Is there a way to fix this stutter or Is there any better approach other then using seek to?

This is what is printed out in console

```
D/CCodecBuffers(17859): [c2.android.aac.decoder#0:1D-Output.Impl[N]] Client returned a buffer it does not own according to our record: 0   
D/CCodecBuffers(17859): [c2.android.aac.decoder#0:1D-Output.Impl[N]] Client returned a buffer it does not own according to our record: 1   
D/CCodecBuffers(17859): [c2.android.aac.decoder#0:1D-Output.Impl[N]] Client returned a buffer it does not own according to our record: 2   
I/CCodecConfig(17859): query failed after returning 16 values (BAD_INDEX)   
W/Codec2Client(17859): query -- param skipped: index = 1342179345.  
W/Codec2Client(17859): query -- param skipped: index = 2415921170.  
W/Codec2Client(17859): query -- param skipped: index = 1610614798.  
D/CCodecBufferChannel(17859): [c2.android.aac.decoder#0] onWorkDone: output format changed to AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {  
D/CCodecBufferChannel(17859):   int32_t channel-count = 2  
D/CCodecBufferChannel(17859):   string mime = "audio/raw"  
D/CCodecBufferChannel(17859):   int32_t sample-rate = 44100   
D/CCodecBufferChannel(17859): }  
D/AudioTrack(17859): getTimestamp_l(909): device stall time corrected using current time 27051635886248
```